# React-Datetime; I'm using two in one component, how do I tell which is which?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datetime

This is an odd question about react-datetime: *Why doesn't the callback allow a "name" to be returned?*

I'm using Daytime twice for "start" and "end" times on a calendar scheduler. But I want to use a single "onChange" event to update state. The problem is: Datetime onChange only returns the time, it doesn't return a name or an ID or any way for me to identify *which Datetime* component is sending the onChange.

Here is the render() code:

```
<CardSubtitle>Start Date:
  <Datetime 
    value = {this.state.start}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    className = "dateTimeModule"
  />
</CardSubtitle>

<CardSubtitle>End Date:
  <Datetime 
    value = {this.state.end}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    className = "dateTimeModule"
  />
</CardSubtitle>
```

And here is the logic I want to use:

```
handleChange = (e) => {

  this.setState({
    bodyEdit: true,
    [e.target.name]:e.target.value
  })
};
```

But "e" only contains the date object. It appears that Datetime doesn't support a "name" return?

I'm confused, it seems like an obvious miss. How do I differentiate between these? Do I need to write separate functions for each?

Thinking about doing this:

```
handleStartChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    startDate: e
  })
};

handleEndChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    endDate: e
  })
};
```

But this seems like unnecessary code.

Comment: Your proposal would work but as you mentionned you can avoid having two functions using my solution hereunder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is pass yourself an additional parameter to your function:

```
        <CardSubtitle>Start Date:
          <Datetime 
            value = {this.state.start}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "start")}
            className = "dateTimeModule"
          />
        </CardSubtitle>

        <CardSubtitle>End Date:
          <Datetime 
            value = {this.state.end}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "end")}
            className = "dateTimeModule"
          />
        </CardSubtitle>
```

and reuse this parameter in your handleChange(e, name) function:

```
  handleChange = (e, name) => {
    this.setState({
      bodyEdit: true,
      [name]:e
    })
  };
```

Also make sure of what is returned by the library you are using as the "e", it doesn't seem to be a classical event but rather a moment object:

> Callback trigger when the date changes. The callback receives the
> selected moment object as only parameter, if the date in the input is
> valid. If the date in the input is not valid, the callback receives
> the value of the input (a string).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This allows me to pass a parameter, however, the state update is being rejected. When I try to change the value in Datetime, it resets to the original value.

Comment: Make usre the state you update end or start is similar named as the one you pass to your component endDate, startDate, as in your various example I saw different naming.